# how do I optimized query having order by clause which takes too much time to execute

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have below query:

```
  SELECT image_hashid_pk,dcthd,mhhd FROM (
 SELECT image_hashid_pk,
 BIT_COUNT(BINARY '1010000110010011000111001100000011110001011110001111111110000101' ^ BINARY dct_binary) AS dcthd,
BIT_COUNT(BINARY '011010011011000111001000111111000011010000111010000101101111000101011001111110110000110010010100101100110101001111011000000011100101110010110100110010110111100100111011000000011011111110000011011001011000011010000011010010010101100101110101101010001001101010000011011101010110101101011011001001001101000011111000010100101001010010000101101000001011101010001111000011110010010010011010011001100100100010011110110100110110100100101101000001110000110011010010111110000111101101111000111111010110111001100110111000000111000000111000000111000010111000000111000000111000000111000000' ^ BINARY mh_binary)/576 AS mhhd
FROM image_hashtest 
 )AS t
WHERE dcthd=0 OR mhhd<=0.05
ORDER BY mhhd,image_hashid_pk ASC;
```

I write it as like below also

```
  SELECT image_hashid_pk,
   BIT_COUNT(BINARY '1010000110010011000111001100000011110001011110001111111110000101' ^ BINARY dct_binary) AS dcthd,
BIT_COUNT(BINARY '011010011011000111001000111111000011010000111010000101101111000101011001111110110000110010010100101100110101001111011000000011100101110010110100110010110111100100111011000000011011111110000011011001011000011010000011010010010101100101110101101010001001101010000011011101010110101101011011001001001101000011111000010100101001010010000101101000001011101010001111000011110010010010011010011001100100100010011110110100110110100100101101000001110000110011010010111110000111101101111000111111010110111001100110111000000111000000111000000111000010111000000111000000111000000111000000' ^ BINARY mh_binary)/576 AS mhhd
FROM image_hashtest HAVING dcthd=0 OR mhhd<=0.05 
 ORDER BY mhhd,image_hashid_pk ASC LIMIT 1;
```

In above query without ordering it takes less time but when I used order by clause on 'mhhd' column it takes too much time .

Can I create index on mhhd or whats the other way to optimized above query please suggest.

Comment: Start here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Comment: I knew this. but I want to know how do I create index on dynamic column .

Comment: here I want to create index on mhhd column because ordering on that column only takes time to execute query

Comment: Do you really use mysql **8.0** already? You know, that it isn't stable, yet?

Comment: yes, I knew , I used it only for some operations which is not supported in mysqlv5.7 for testing

Comment: You may get idea to create appropriate index from here
 https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/